# grep from var into a new var

Tags: regex, bash, variables, grep, match

I've been trying these now for some hours and it only works if I use a single line instead of a var full of parsed data.

What I'm doing is:

Login with curl, navigate to subsite and store this within a variable like:

```
# get_token
login_token=$(curl --insecure --cookie-jar $COOKIE -L <website> --stderr - | grep -Pzo "(?<=type.\=.\"hidden\".name.\=.\"login_token\".value.\=.\")(.+)(?=\")")

# login
curl --insecure --cookie $COOKIE --cookie-jar $COOKIE --data "&login_token=$login_token&username=$LOGIN&password=$PASS&pin=$PIN&submit=submit" <website>

# getdata
var=$( curl --insecure --cookie $COOKIE --cookie-jar $COOKIE -L <websitesubpage>)
```

Everything works like a charm, but now I'm stuck.

I'm trying to get an id from within `$var`:

```
get_id=${ grep -Pzo "(?<=URL\=\.\/details.php\?id\=)(.+)(?=&)" <<< "$var"} #dont work

get_id="`echo "$var" | grep -Pzo '?<=URL\=\.\/details.php\?id\=)(.+)(?=&)'`" #dont work
```

and so on.

The regex must be OK, I've tested it multiple times. But here is the string from which I need the id:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=./details.php?id=196417&readed=yes" />
```

or also within the response:

```
<p style="text-align:center"><a href="details.php?id=196417">Go ahead</a></p>
</td></tr></table><br>
```

It would be great if someone could help me.

Comment: The syntax for running nested commands is command-substitution with syntax `$(..)`, `${..}` is for expanding variables do `get_id=$( grep -Pzo "(?<=URL\=\.\/details.php\?id\=)(.+)(?=&)" <<< "$var" )`. 
There is also an outdated construct for doing the same over `$(..)`, using back-ticks `` which is not recommended and gets quite messy when using nested quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This work for all use cases :

```
id=$( grep -oP 'details\.php\?id\=\K\d+' <<< "$var" )
```

Note the use of `$( )` for *command substitution*, even nested. The only proper way in 2018

Comment: thank you, this works great ! 
you saved me much more hours with headache.